# Is it inefficient to store large objects in unordered_map?

Tags: c++

If you have for example unordered_map and add items, when unordered_map does a rehash is it actually moving the BigObject data around or just internally moving pointers ?  Would it be better to uses unordered_map< int, shared_ptr > ?

Comment: I think this will depend on how the standard library you are using implements `unordered_map`.

Comment: It should be straightforward to test your current implementation of unordered_map by writing a little tester-class that prints out debug-prints in its move/copy constructors, etc.  (Of course that only tells you the behavior of your own STL implementation, it won't tell you what other STL implementations might do)

Comment: I did a test now and it doesn’t call copy ctor or assignment operator so I assume no moves are done.  Was thinking maybe it could do a swap though.

Answer (score 4):

Each element is stored in its own node, thus adding / removing elements does not ever move an existing element.

How can you know that? Just take a cursory look at the public interface, specifically taking note of the methods [`.extract()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/extract) and [`.merge()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/merge). The others changing the number of elements aren't as blatant.

Comment: I found that unordered map only needs the value to be DefaultConstructible so this suggests no copying is needed.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the implementation of `std::unordered_map`. VS's implementation stores data in a linked list. So it is both good and bad. Bad since it is not contiguous and requires allocation for each element (it is difficult to implement `std::unordered_map` without this issue) but good in the sense that it doesn't even move elements around.

Regardless of implementation, you shouldn't use `std::shared_ptr` unless you want to share data ownership. It will most likely slow down your code considerably due extra allocations, multitude of pointer dereferences, and dealing with atomic operations in the control block of the shared pointer.

In extreme cases, when size of the element is extremely large, consider using `std::unique_ptr`. I don't see any other case when it makes any sense to do so (lest ofcourse, the elements are not movable).

Comment: A linked list? Hardly. That could not fulfill the performance requirements. A bunch of nodes? Yes.

Comment: Correct on the dependence on implementation, but you would generally expect a hash-table for [std::unordered_map](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)

Comment: @Deduplicator it stores the values in a linked list. It also has a vector (I believe) that maps hash_values to the associated element in the linked list.